# {"code":"SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN"}

Tags: node.js, npm

```
{"code":"SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN"}
```

Im getting above error out of the blue when I invoke Node API which will call an external API, I tried with setting npm strict-ssl flag to false and upgrading npm as well, none of them worked, how can I fix this error?

Comment: Try this if you haven't tried before, `npm config set strict-ssl false` and then `npm install -g npm@latest` then execute your program.

Comment: You should let the OP know just how dangerous that can be.

Comment: @jas- Yup.. It is indeed.. But it can be useful while troubleshooting.

Comment: I think a better option would be to use the OpenSSL `s_client `` tool.

Comment: @jas-can you please elaborate how to use openssl s-client tool?